# custom icon not showing up in iron-icon

Tags: svg, polymer, iron

I'm trying to use some custom svg icon in iron-icon element but it's not showing up. All standard icons from iron-iconset are working great.
I linked all neccessary polymer libraries but it's still haven't resolved my problem

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/av-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/social-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/image-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-image/iron-image.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.html">
<link rel="import" href="custom-icon.html">

<iron-icon icon="custom-icon:my-icon"></iron-icon>
```

here is **custom-icon.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../js/bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="../js/bower_components/iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.html">

<iron-iconset-svg name="custom" size=4>
    <svg>
        <defs>
            <g id="nodejs">
                <path d="M116.504151,3.58037736 C123.46566,-0.404528302...
            </g>
</iron-iconset-svg>
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess

```
<iron-icon icon="custom-icon:my-icon"></iron-icon>
```

should be

```
<iron-icon icon="custom:my-icon"></iron-icon>
```

(`my-icon` should be `nodejs` according to your example, but I assume your iconset contains a `<g id="my-icon">`)

or alterantively

```
<iron-iconset-svg name="custom" size=4>
```

should be

```
<iron-iconset-svg name="custom-icon" size=4>
```

Comment: sorry it was my copy-paste mistake I changed a bit my code like for the example but I did everything right like you said `<iron-icon icon="custom:my-icon"></iron-icon>` but still having problem

Comment: But it still doesn't work? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: no I havent errors and in source html code it looks like icon is there but for some reason doesn't show up

Comment: Maybe you just need to set a color?

Comment: no it's right. I have several objects with icons some of them are from standard library (they're working great) and others custom. I think my svg a bit large and I can't see it. may be this is the reason? how can I resize svg file?

Comment: Try increasing `size="4"` to `size="150"`

Comment: yes, it works! thank you very much. I though the more is the value than the bigger is the size and in this case vice versa or what?

Comment: I stumbled upon this myself recently :). I think SVGs `viewport` can be used to modify the actual size (don't remember).